# Como mudar chave primária que referencia chave estrangeira para auto increment

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas, uma chamada `aluno` e outra chamada `HistoricoAluno`. Após criá-las, faltou uma alteração que era deixar a chave primária da tabela `alunos` como `auto_increment`. Ao tentar fazer essa alteração sempre recebo o seguinte erro:

```
    Query error:
#1833 - Cannot change column 'idAluno': used in a foreign key constraint 'historicoaluno_ibfk_1' of table 'matriculas.historicoaluno
```

Então tentei algumas soluções, como esta:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

/* realizar as alterações */

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Mas não obtive êxito. Como posso deixar a chave primária da tabela `alunos` como `auto_increment`?

Estou usando o mySQL no phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Ambas as tabela (ou alguma delas) possui registros?

Comment: Antes eu tentei inserir na tabela de alunos, e só conseguia inserir quando informava o id(diferente dos que tinham lá). Agora as duas estão sem registros e do mesmo jeito não consigo fazer a alteração.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa remover a referência de Fk antes de alterar a coluna na outra tabela, tente assim:

```
-- Desabilita as verificações de FKs
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- Deleta a referência de FK da tabela HistoricoAluno
ALTER TABLE HistoricoAluno DROP FOREIGN KEY historicoaluno_ibfk_1;

-- Altera a coluna idAluno para AUTO_INCREMENT na tabela Aluno
ALTER TABLE Aluno MODIFY COLUMN idAluno INT AUTO_INCREMENT;

-- Cria a FK novamente
ALTER TABLE HistoricoAluno ADD CONSTRAINT historicoaluno_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (idAluno) REFERENCES Aluno(idAluno);

-- Habilita as verificações de FKs
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

**Obs.:** É importante ressaltar que as colunas da FK devem possuir a mesma configuração (tipo, tamanho, assinatura, etc...).

Comment: Funcionou direitinho!